# How to share video file (DVD) in company's network to employees without them being able to take it home?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, video-streaming, share, windows-sbs-2003, video-hosting

I have small network with 50+ users with `SBS 2003`, `MOSS 2007` and `File server` (all Microsoft software). We've got some video's that we want to share with users without them being able to save it and take home (don't want them to end up on youtube).

How to approach this ? What possible solutions could I use for this considering software I have and `limited` resources to buy additional software (although reasonably priced would be ok)? I guess having it on MOSS would be best idea (although I guess I would have to convert it someway and put it up properly) but other ideas are welcome?

Comment: There isn't a format that is 100% perfect. There is always a way to take it home if you really want to. Convert it to an FLV and play it with JWPlayer on a page. That will keep off 95% of not to tech savy people.

Comment: My client is in finance business so there's no tech savy people except me. But i prefer to be safe then sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to convert it to a format that plays off a website, stick it on your company website or reverse-proxy it so it only allows IP's from within your Intranet to get the page with the link. That should limit who can view the video from your server.

Then remind people that if it leaves the company it's a firable offense by policy.

As others have pointed out there's always a way to get digital information and steal it, even if it's by pointing a cell camera at the screen and recording it. If it's extremely proprietary information you can't just serve it out to people on the network and not risk it being stolen to some degree.

Alternatively you could just put the files into a share with particular permissions to restrict who gets to it.

Depending on how far you want to take it and how much space you have dedicated to file storage, you could embed information into the files, like a pixel marking of some kind or a special numbering tagged into some frames, that are then compressed into a small video and set permissions such that only certain people have access to even list certain versions of the video. Then if it is leaked you know who's login was used to access it. It won't stop the leak but it'll tell you who is most likely responsible. Or directly give it to the users and tell them that it's been tagged so you know what version goes to who, and they have to return the USB drive or CD when finished (I don't know the nature of the video you're distributing.)

Last would be to show the video to people at a mandatory meeting and then not allow access to it again. It's really the best way to control whatever the content is. Anything else still takes the risk of theft in some way.

Comment: It's a bunch of movies (advertisement) that we created during integration day (by professional movie makers - part of team building exercises). It's not something really bad or unmoral but would look unprofessional if it comes out.

Comment: If it's something like that, do it during a company-wide meeting to view the contents for everyone to have a peek at the same time.

Comment: Use the Facebook Rule: Never create anything that you wouldn't mind Mom seeing online.